# To read the specific data from file and should save it new file in python

Tags: python

Example need to extract certain company employee details from list of all company employees and save it in new folder,
I know to read the files from folder.

```
fvar=open(r'D:\Employee Details .txt','r')
res=fvar.readlines()
fvar.close()
print(res)
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Please explain in detail

Comment: Your script works. What is wrong?

Comment: fvar=open(r'D:\Eployee Details.rtf','r')
res=fvar.readlines()
fvar.close()
print(res)
res1= res
fvar=open(r'D:\New details.rtf','w')
for i in res1:
    fvar.write(i)
    fvar.write("\n")
fvar.close()
this the whole program...i want to extract specific employee detaisl while writing into new file

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to save the details in a new txt file in a specific folder.
So you have to expand your Code with something like this:

```
newfile =open("C:/MyFolder/new.txt",'w')
for item in res:
    newfile.write(item)
newfile.close
```

This is, because your res variable is a list. And you have to iterate through the list and write every single item.

Comment: thank u so much actually i am stuck with how to extract particular values from data in read file while writing into new file..like extracting particualr company employee details in all the given employees data,,

Comment: fvar=open(r'D:\Eployee Details.rtf','r')
res=fvar.readlines()
fvar.close()
print(res)
res1= res
fvar=open(r'D:\New details.rtf','w')
for i in res1:
    fvar.write(i)
    fvar.write("\n")
fvar.close()
this was the code i have written..